# luacode works with \newcommand but not with \NewDocumentCommand

Tags: luatex, xparse, luacode

Imagine the following code:

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\HelloWorld}{}{Hello World}
\newcommand{\DefaultHelloWorld}{Hello World}

\begin{luacode}
    luatexbase.add_to_callback("wrapup_run", function()
        io.write("\HelloWorld")
        -- io.write("\DefaultHelloWorld")
    end, "Post-process pdf")
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
    Hello World!
\end{document}
```

Why is it that using `\newcommand` works perfectly fine and expands into `io.write("Hello World")`, but as soon as I switch to `\NewDocumentCommand` I get the following error (excerpt of log file):

```
Package: xparse 2023-10-10 L3 Experimental document command parser
)[\directlua]:2: invalid escape sequence near '"\H'.
\luacode@dbg@exec ...code@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }
                                           
l.14 \end{luacode}
           
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.
```

Comment: Commands defined with \NewDocumentCommand are protected and so not expandable. You end up with `\HelloWorld` in the lua.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer)

Just had to switch to `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`:

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{luacode}
% \usepackage{xparse} % REMOVED -- see @David Carlisle's comment

\NewDocumentCommand{\OldHelloWorld}{}{Hello World}        % OLD
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\HelloWorld}{}{Hello World} % NEW -- working
\newcommand{\DefaultHelloWorld}{Hello World}

\begin{luacode}
    luatexbase.add_to_callback("wrapup_run", function()
        io.write("\HelloWorld")
        -- io.write("\DefaultHelloWorld")
    end, "Post-process pdf")
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
    Hello World!
\end{document}
```

Comment: you only need `xparse` package if you have an old latex release, the commands are predefined in latex in current releases.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I've edited the answer